# Is there a way to make Multi - Level row grouping table in R DT pacakge

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, shinydashboard, dt

I'am finding ways to make multi-level row grouping table using DT in R

According to Datatables' documentation(https://datatables.net/extensions/rowgroup/examples/initialisation/multipleGroups.html), I tried multi-level row-grouping. But It didn't work

here is my example code

```
datatable(render_df,
          class = 'cell-border stripe',
          container =  container, 
          rownames = F, 
          extensions = 'RowGroup', 
          options = list(searching=FALSE,
                         lengthChange = FALSE,
                         info = F, 
                         ordering=F,
                         paging=F,
                         rowGroup = list(dataSrc=c(1,0)),
                         columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=c(0, 1)),
                                           list(className = 'dt-body-left',
                                                targets = seq(2)),
                                           list(className = 'dt-body-right',
                                                targets = seq(3:18)),
                                           list(width = '10%',
                                                targets = 2),
                                           list(width = col.width,
                                                targets = c(3:col.cnt))
                                           ),
                         pageLength = 20))
```

The result of this code is just 'No group'

Does anyone tried this multi-level row grouping before?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem myself fortunatly :).

For someone who want to use this functionality, I share my solution.

I compared Datatables extentions between official service and R DT package. I found that R DT's RowGroup version is quite old, so I downloaded latest version of Rowgroup extensions (https://datatables.net/download/index, only checked RowGroup) and changed RowGroup extension file in R/win-library/3.6/DT/htmlwidgets/lib/datatables (maybe this will be changed depending on your setting and OS. ) by downloaded file.

I didn't check any other possible error or bugs, but above code will work well.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering about this it is actually possible to do multiple row grouping with the current DT version (0.30). Not sure since when it was implemented.

Similarly to the example in the [documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html):

```r
mtcars2 = mtcars[1:20, ]
DT::datatable(
    mtcars2[order(mtcars2$cyl), ],
    extensions = 'RowGroup',
    options = list(rowGroup = list(dataSrc = c(10,2))),
    selection = 'none'
)
```